# Performance Difference between display: none and height: 0px, footer React component

Tags: reactjs, height, display

I've seen a lot of post talking about display vs visibility vs opacity but in my case I need something more along the lines of display none but I don't want the cost associated with having the browser completely rerender what in this case is a footer React component. Thus I wanted to know if there is a performance benefit of setting the height to 0px instead of setting the display to none. The component will always be rendered on the page as well.

Comment: For react, there is no difference between `height 0px`  and `display: none`. The best performing react solution is to not render the component at all. So why is "will always be rendered" a requirement? There is a css performance difference: (`display: none` is faster).

Comment: @wintvlt For performance reasons I use flowrouter and never de-render any routes taking into account native development paradigms for meteor ios development. Because of this, I never derender the footer which is a tabbar but instead just display none it according to the route. For the main routes its necessary, for child routes not so much, this is where the question stemmed from

Comment: Well then: if you do not derender: display none is probably the best route (pun intended) to go. But changing props (or any other CSS) inevitably means rerender = performance hurt, so you would have to compare performance of rerendering route with display none vs derender. Again, if you do not want to derender, then safest bet is display none.